# Литература по математическим задачам в программировании (C++/C#)

Tags: c#, c++

Хочу освежить память и навыки в плане математических методов в программировании, т.к. в своей работе непосредственно с мат.расчетами почти не работал со времен института, и сейчас ощущаю, что сколь-нибудь сложные расчеты заставляют снова слишком долго думать )

Потому хотелось бы потренироваться на задачках возможно даже институтского курса.
Языки предпочтительнее конечно C++/C#, но в принципе сойдет любой не-доисторический.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Носач В.В. Решение задач аппроксимации...
Правда, все на Бэйсике. Найдете djvu-файлы, если погуглите.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вот [эта](http://books.google.ru/books/about/C++_Solutions_For_Mathematical_Problems.html?id=IcnIWqUMFEgC&redir_esc=y) и [эта](http://www.amazon.com/C-Mathematicians-Introduction-Students-Professionals/dp/158488584X) книги будут вам полезны. Они, правда, на английском и вряд ли переводились на русский, да и задачниками, как таковыми, не являются, но содержат по-моему, вполне полезную информацию

Answer (score 1):

Очень интересные задачи возникают на разных порталах. Например [codeforces.ru](http://codeforces.ru/) или 
[russiancodecup.ru](http://russiancodecup.ru/about/). Задачки очень интересные - уровня олимпиады. К тому же можно заодно и участие принять =). А [вот](http://ru.brainexer.com/)  просто размять мозг.

Answer (score 0):

К слову о интернет-задачниках. [Тут](http://acmp.ru) тоже неплохие задачи на многих языках программирования.